# must click twice for state to be set and then call function

Tags: reactjs

i am trying to set the state to a number and then run a function on click, but right now I have have to click twice for it to function properly. I'm unsure of why this is happening and possible solutions for this issue.  I have a select and when I select a number, I would like it to fire the fetch for that amount of items in my database.  my code is as follows:

fetchNext function:

```
  const fetchNext = async () => {
    const token = await localStorage.FBIdToken

    console.log("I'm running", formData.limit)
    const limit = formData.limit

    await axios
      .get(`/user?limit=${limit}`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `${token}`
        }
      })
      .then(res => {
        setUser(res.data)
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
```

here is the select:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react'

// MUI stuff
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select'
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel'
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem'
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl'

const SelectLimit = ({ limit, fetchNext, handleInputChange }) => {
  const inputLabel = useRef(null)

  return (
    <FormControl style={{ width: '100%' }}>
      <InputLabel ref={inputLabel} id="demo-simple-select-outlined-label">
        Type
      </InputLabel>
      <Select
        labelId="demo-simple-select-outlined-label"
        id="demo-simple-select-outlined"
        value={limit}
        onChange={handleInputChange('limit')}
        onClick={fetchNext}
        fullWidth
      >
        <MenuItem value="5">5</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value="10">10</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value="20">20</MenuItem>
      </Select>
    </FormControl>
  )
}

export default SelectLimit
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your onChange

```
onChange = {(e) => handleInputChange(e.target.value)}
```

I hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: my handleInput change is as follows:   const handleInputChange = field => e => {
    setFormData({ ...formData, [field]: e.target.value })
  }